# How to read keywords from an image file?

Tags: c#, image, metadata, keyword, xmp

I would like to read the ITPC keywords from an image file. I want to use this to detect if any of my ~20.000 images don't have keywords assigned to them.
Additionally I would like to read the actual format of the image (jpeg, gif...), regardless of which extension it has.
Bonus is being able to read other info like dimensions and size as I go.

I have found many 'solutions' online but none of them work or they are painfully slow.

For example I tried this 'brute force' solution:

```
byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
var asString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(image);
var start = asString.IndexOf("<x:xmpmeta");
var end = asString.IndexOf("</x:xmpmeta>") + 12;
if (start == -1 || end == -1 || end < start)
  return;
var justTheMeta = asString.Substring(start, end - start);
var returnVal = new XmlDocument();
```

But it was way too slow to even wait for it to finish fully processing. And I didn't even complete the code yet (reading the actual keywords).

My best bet seems to be this dotNET wrapper of Adobe's XMP SDK.
https://github.com/drewnoakes/xmp-core-dotnet

But documentation is pretty much non-existant. I could only find this example but it doesn't work as it seems to expect an XMP file but all I have is an image (gif, jpeg, png) file.

```
IXmpMeta xmp;
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("some-file.xmp"))
    xmp = XmpMetaFactory.Parse(stream);

foreach (var property in xmp.Properties)
    Console.WriteLine($"Path={property.Path} Namespace={property.Namespace} Value={property.Value}");
```

I tried doing it like this but it gives me an XML Parsing failure on every image:

```
IXmpMeta xmp;
try
{
    byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
    xmp = XmpMetaFactory.ParseFromBuffer(image);

    foreach (var property in xmp.Properties)
    Console.WriteLine($"Path={property.Path} Namespace={property.Namespace} Value={property.Value}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I think the XML is fine. I can open my images in Notepad++ and I see the XML with the keywords in it right there. And all keywords are displayed fine in image programs like ACDSee and Photoshop.

Could somebody please help out with a code example that actually works and is fairly efficient as well? I need to incorporate this into my C# program.

Comment: Do you need to do it programmatically?  If not, you could use [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).  Assuming you mean IPTC Core and not IPTC IIM, a command like `exiftool -Subject -FileType -ImageSize -FileSize <DIR>` would read and output all the data you mention.  Additionally, the output can be formatted as a CSV, JSON, or XML file in addition to plain text.

Comment: I actually do need to do it programmatically. It will be part of a larger application that I am building to analyse my image library. In C#.

Answer (score 0):

You were really close with the Drew Noakes XMP library... What you really want is this: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet

Code looks something like this:

```
   var metadata = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(imagePath);

   var IPTCdir = metadata.OfType<IptcDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();

   if (IPTCdir != null)
   {
      var caption = IPTCdir.SafeExifGetString(IptcDirectory.TagCaption);

      imgMetaData.Caption = FilteredDescription(caption);

      var keywordList = IPTCdir?.GetStringArray(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords);
   }
```